# jquery Validation plugin, change class on 'invalid'

Tags: jquery, validation, error-handling

Currently I'm using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation for validating my forms clientside, and currently, I'm using the 
**success** parameter that you can set in the validator, when it succeeds it adds a 'checked' class which has some styling. But is there a way to check whether the user changed the input afterwards in a wrong way? And can one change the class from 'checked' to 'error' again?

Currently I have:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(form) {form.submit();},
    success: function(label) {
        // set &nbsp; as text for IE
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Together with the whole validation rules and so on.

Hope any can help! Thank you a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick. For *yourInputForm* you enter the input field's descriptor and for 
*yourValidationRuleAsABooleanExpression* a boolean expression that represents your validation rule.

```
$( yourInputForm ).keyup(function() {
if( yourValidationRuleAsABooleanExpression ) {
     $(this).addClass('checked').removeClass('error');
} else $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('error'):
```

});

This method checks the user's input for your validation rule the moment he typed it and will add and remove the according classes.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hmm, I will try keinabel! Weird that there isn't a function for it, in the jquery validation plugin

Comment: @Zerpex, I don't know about that. Did not check the plugin before. I simply tried the above code and when it worked I posted my answer to you. Don't hesitate to ask if this does not work.

Comment: I will try search if it's already included in the plugin, would be easier I think!

Comment: Can you tell me what you found out?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the showLabel function to remove the 'checked' class ( i.e. add `.removeClass('checked')`)

The minified js:

```
showLabel:function(a,b){var d=this.errorsFor(a);if(d.length){d.removeClass(this.settings.validClass).removeClass('checked')
```

Non-Minified js:

```
showLabel: function(element, message) {
        var label = this.errorsFor( element );
        if ( label.length ) {
            // refresh error/success class
            label.removeClass( this.settings.validClass ).removeClass('checked').addClass( this.settings.errorClass );
```